# Can't compile c++ program with SFML library

Tags: c++, linker, sfml

I want to learn SFML library now.
My OS is Windows 8.1 and I don't use any IDE, only Makefiles. Compiler is g++ MinGW 4.8.1

I have downloaded SFML files from official site, then copied "include"-folder of SFML to "include"-folder of MinGW, "lib" and "bin" too.

Now I want to compile simple program like in example on official site.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with such command line

g++ test.o -o main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

But I have many errors like this

`test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to _imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale`

What am i doing wrong?

I have a guess, may be is it something wrong with PATH variable. But I don't understand what should I write there.

Upd:

Here's all linker's errors:

```
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x147): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf11CircleShapeC1Efj'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Color5GreenE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Shape12setFillColorERKNS_5ColorE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2b2): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2ec): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
c:/program files (x86)/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: test.o: bad reloc address 0xf in section `.text$_ZN2sf6StringD1Ev[__ZN2sf6StringD1Ev]'
c:/program files (x86)/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Version of SFML is 2.2

I still need help (see comments below)

Comment: Try adding `-lstdc++`

Comment: Could you list all the unresolved externals? This will help a lot.

Comment: Also make sure you have the folder for the library files in your linker search path.

Comment: Which version of SFML are you using?

Comment: @OMGtechy where can i edit linker search path?

Comment: Before you do that, try adding -DSFML_STATIC. If that doesn't work, use google to find out how to edit the search path.

Comment: @OMGtechy am i not right that at first linker will search libs in default "lib"-folder? If I copied there all SFML-files from SFML "lib"-folder, wouldn't it work?

Comment: " then copied "include"-folder of SFML to "include"-folder of MinGW" —  bad idea, why do that? Read the guide http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php (the IDE is not important).

Comment: Indeed, it should. I take it the static solution didn't work?

Comment: @n.m. where should i edit this setting when i compile with command line?

Comment: @OMGtechy yeah, it didn't work.

Comment: Use `-I<include-dir>` and `-L`<library-dir>`, read gcc help/userguide for these options. Make sure your libs are for the right architecture (x86 vs x86-64).

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, error was with libs, I have downloaded x64-libs instead x32. Ok, I Have successfully compiled, but now I have such runtime rror: "procedure entry point _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz not found in dll library ...". All sfml-dll I have copied to folder with cpp and exe files.

Comment: You'll need to make sure not only the architecture matches, but also the exact version of mingw you're using. Your best bet is to compile SFML from source with your compiler, just to ensure compatibility. Ultimately, I'd recommend you just use visual studio if you are on windows anyway, There are nuget and vcpkg packages for SFML so you don't have to do any messing about with linker settings